# How make real time notification laravel with firebase?

Tags: laravel, real-time, firebase-notifications

I created laravel web about  hospital  i want to notified the user when the doctor upload file treatment i don't want use the pusher because expensive for me now ..so any way to do with firebase it's better if now video or article showing me step by step AND how connect the icon when upload the user get notification

Comment: check this https://github.com/Edujugon/PushNotification, it's free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Notifications in Laravel, here is the documentation for the details: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications

I'm not sure what notification channel would you like to use, Firebase Cloud Messaging is not supported by default, but there is a 3rd party package for that: https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/fcm

You can find a lot of custom notification channels here: https://laravel-notification-channels.com/

Comment: i wanana notification like facebook

Comment: any video step by step can watch it?